# Synchronising files over SSH

Tags: sync, ssh

I have an SSH server providing access to my files at home, secured by a private key.

I'd like to be able to synchronise those files with my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Note, running Cyanogenmod 11 (Android 4.4.2).  I need two-way synchronisation: edits and deletes on the phone should be synchronised to the server, and edits and deletes on the server should be synchronised to the phone.

Ideally, this tool would run in the background, but I would be able to trigger it manually if required.

Does such a tool exist?  I've been unable to find one either in the Play Store or F-Droid.

Comment: 3 and a half years later and still no solution for this simple task. None of the software from answers are working/maintained today.

Comment: @madneon I've added a new answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186319/56413

Comment: thanks for mentioning, but it seems Syncthing requires installing peer2peer agents, which doesnt suits me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revisiting this after several years, I've found a solution that works across all my devices (GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, Android): [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/)

It provides free (as in speech, and as in beer), secure, and easily installed peer to peer file synchronisation.  Literally does everything I want, out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want a tool with a nice GUI, take a look at [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). It not only offers SSH, but plenty of additional protocols – including Samba, FTP, and a bunch of cloud services (yes, even ownCloud). More alternatives can be found [in my list here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync).

Answer (score 1):

[Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is a great utility that can synchronize files using SSH, which I personally and at work for backups.  Looks like there is an app available in the Play Store called [rsync backup for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android).

EDIT: Also if you want a more Linux-y type solution, CM has busybox included, which I believe has rsync. Looks like this guy has a setup that seems similar to what you want.  Check out his [blog post](http://cschramm.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-backup-using-rsync.html).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I ended up choosing [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), which supports Linux, FreeBSD, Windows and Android - the full set of OSs I use on a regular basis.</strike>

See [https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65691/synchronising-files-over-ssh](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186319/56413) for my replacement for Unison.